# Force Templated Constructor to Run?

Tags: c++, templates

I know there is a initailzer trick to forcing a global object to be constructed regardless of where it is used. This is used for std::cout i believe.

```
#ifndef GUARD_H
#define GUARD_H

class Magical
{
   // default constructor and such...
};

class Init
{
public:
    Init();
};

extern Magical& magic;

namespace
{
    Init __magical_initializer; // works as this object is constructed in every source file it is included in
}

#endif
```

src:

```
#include "magical.h"

#include <new>

static int count; // believe there is a spec somewhere which states global integers are initialized with zero

static alignas(Magical) char buffer[sizeof(Magical)];

Magical& magic = *reinterpret_cast<Magical*>(buffer);

Init::Init()
{
    if(!count++)
    {
        new(buffer) Magical;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a template equivalent to this, as such my code would look something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{

    static Magical<T> __private; // need this constructor to be called.

};

// usage:

class SomeClass : public Base<SomeClass>
{
};
```

Comment: Are you looking for a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: @aruisdante I don't need to use the object though, that's the problem, it's being optimized out so the constructor never gets called. But I need the constructor to be called as it does some work, essentially adding information based on the templated class.

Comment: @aruisdante I've used a singleton (function based static) and tested on several compilers and seems it doesn't optimize out the object. So long as i add the instance function to the object constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to solve this problem as templates can't exist in source files.